# How can I fetch live script data from a url like Firebug does?

Tags: javascript

In Firebug (or any browser DevTools) you can continuously fetch script data from a URL.

How can I continuously fetch the scripts resources like them?
It should be easy but I could not find it in Firebug's source code.

I am open to use any programming or scripting language.

P.S.: I'm mostly interested to perceive XHRs.

Comment: What do you mean, "continuously"?

Comment: And which data exactly are you interested in?